# iOS: NSURLCache with NSURLSession alongside HTTP headers

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, nsurlcache

`NSURLCache` is some kind of a dark art magic that is neither documented properly, nor behaves as expected.

I am using `AFNetworking`'s `AFHTTPSessionManager` to utilise NSURLSession. I am using [this](http://www.mocky.io/) mocking service to create custom HTTP responses.

I am setting the NSURLCache with disk capacity and all the cache policies.

Then in the `URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError` method of `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`, I am doing this:

```
    NSURLRequest *request = task.currentRequest;

    NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request];
```

The documentation states about the `cachedResponseForRequest:`

> @result The NSCachedURLResponse stored in the cache with the given
>       request, or nil if there is no NSCachedURLResponse stored with the
>       given request.

AFNetworking's FAQ states:

> So long as your NSURLRequest objects have the correct cache policy,
>   and your server response contains a valid Cache-Control header,
>   responses will be automatically cached for subsequent requests.

After all this my assumption is that the value of the the `cachedResponse` variable will be nil if the Cache-Control is NOT set properly. However, whatever I have tried to do so far - setting it to 'private', 'no-cache' or whatever - the cachedResponse ALWAYS contains the cached response. How can I verify that the caching mechanism works as expected ? Is there anything that I am missing from the setup ?

I have been doing my tests by firstly making the request online, then switching off the internet on my computer. XCode 7.0 beta iOS 9.0.

Any help is appreciated.